# Adding images to maps with Leafpop

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to add separate images to popups so that as you click on each location, an image specific to that place/popup appears. I've figured out how to get one image in, but it applies to all of the popups on the map instead of just one. I have been trying to use the package leafpop for this, but I can't really figure out how to make it work. Even if I just use one image, nothing appears on the map.

This is what my code looks like for it:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)

img = system.file("file/image_name.jpg", package = "jpg")

leaflet(map) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(label = map@data$name,
                   weight = 2,
                   color = "grey",
                   fillColor = "red",
                   fillOpacity = 0.7)%>%
addPopupImages(img, group = "map")
```

I know there's some bits in there that I'm not quite doing right. At this point, I just want to know if it's even possible to do this the way I'm envisioning. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The images need to be in a vector of the same length as the points passed to leaflet. Here is a reproducible example you can copy paste that will get you started:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)

pts <- tibble(x = runif(10, 175, 176), 
              y = runif(10, -38, -37)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

img <- glue::glue("https://github.com/IQAndreas/sample-images/blob/gh-pages/100-100-color/{11:20}.jpg?raw=true")

pts$img <- img

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = pts, group = "pts") %>%
  addPopupImages(pts$img, group = "pts")
```

Comment: Awesome, that definitely got me started. Now I'm just trying to work out how to get it to work with local images. I've been trying to use the last bit of code from the leafpop pdf, where it starts with the "## Local Images":

https://rdrr.io/github/r-spatial/leafpop/man/addPopupImages.html


`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, with the help of Rich Pauloo! This is the code I ended up using the get local image files. It's a little clunky, but it worked out for me:

```
data_name <- readOGR("data/map_file.kml")

data_name2 <- data.frame(data_name)

pts <- st_as_sf(data.frame(data_name2),
                coords = c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), crs = 4326)

img <- c("images/picture_name.jpg") ##did this for every image I wanted to use, in the order 
##that matched up with the data points I wanted them associated with.

pts$img <- img

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = pts, group = "pts") %>%
  addPopupImages(pts$img, group = "pts", width = 300)
```

Sorry if my conventions for writing out code are not quite right for the website. I just wanted to keep things generic and not include any of my file names or anything.